# rails - undefined method `model_name'

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a basic blogging site in which I want to allow users to offer 'corrections' to posts (just think of it as a comment). The correction object belongs to a post, which in turn belongs to a user (for which I'm using Devise).

I would like the form to create a new correction to be nested in the page for the post,so I'm just rendering the form in posts/show.html.erb with `<% render :template => "corrections/new" %>`. I'm getting a 'undefined method model_name' error from the line form_for line in corrections/new.html.erb though.

Here's the form:

```
<% form_for [@correction, :url=> user_post_corrections_path(current_user, @post, @correction)], html: { multipart: true} do |f| %>
  <div class="field">
    <%= f.label :correction %>
    <%= f.text_field :correction %>
  </div>
  <div class="actions">
    <%= f.submit %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

Here's the corrections_controller:

```
class CorrectionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @correction = current_user.@post.corrections.build
    respond_with(@correction)
  end

  def create
    @post = Post.find(params[:post_id])
    @correction = current_user.@post.corrections.build
    if @correction.save
      redirect_to user_post_path(current_user, @correction.post_id)
    end
  end
end
```

In my routes.rb:

```
  resources :users do
    resources :posts do
      resources :corrections
      end
    end
```

Any help with this would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This line looks off:

```
@correction = current_user.@post.corrections.build
```

`@post` is an instance variable, not a method on `current_user`

Did you intend to build a correct with the current user? The following should work:

```
@post.corrections.build(user: current_user)
```

If your corrections model `has_many :users, through: :posts`, then the following should work:

```
@post.corrections.build(users: [current_user])
```

**EDIT**

The format of your form_for is also incorrect. The `url:` key in `form_for` doesn't belong in the resource array (the first arg in your form_for)

The following modification should resolve the error, provided `user_post_corrections_path` takes `:id`, `:post_id`, and `:correction_id`

```
form_for @correction, url: user_post_corrections_path(current_user, @post, @correction), html: { multipart: true} do |f|
```

I'd also reduce your routing to two levels of nesting if possible.

Perhaps this is easier?

```
resources :posts do
  resources :corrections
  end
end
```

If it's implied a post belongs to the `current_user` then it may not be necessary to have `/users` in the route path.

Comment: I want to build a correction that belongs to a post which belongs to a user.

Having said that, it suddenly occurs to me that the post already belongs to the user and so there's no need to reference the user when building the correction.

Unfortunately I'm still getting the same error with `@post.corrections.build`.

Comment: Is the full error `undefined method model_name for nil:NilClass`?

Comment: No, it's `undefined method \`model_name' for {:url=>"/users/1/posts/2/corrections"}:Hash`. The user_id (1) and post_id (2) are correct in that path.

Comment: Oh, I just saw your edit. That fixed it! Thanks very much!

Answer (score 2):

There are several issues I can see, first off:

The form is not rendered:
The form for should be evaluated not computed so you should use <%= %> tag instead of <%%> tag, so it becomes:

```
<%= form_for @correction, url: user_post_corrections_path(current_user, @post, @correction), html: { multipart: true} do |f| %>
```

Second: You are saying form_for @correction, and you said this form is shown in posts/show, this means that the show action for the post should have the following in its controller:

```
@correction = Correction.new user: current_user, post: @post
```

This is assuming you are using the @post variable for the post show meaning you have something like

```
@post = Post.find params[:id]
```

This line is completely off

```
@correction = current_user.@post.corrections.build
```

you can just say:

```
@correction = Correction.new correction_params
@correction.user = current_user
@correction.post = @post
if @correction.save
  redirect_to user_post_path(current_user, @correction.post_id)
end
```

The important part is your show action on the posts controller having the initialization of your @correction object.

Comment: Very informative post, thank you. Unfortunately it didn't fix my problem. I'm still getting the same error.